# .htaccess handling two different pages

Tags: .htaccess

I got two pages that handle the params and display relative pages, first is the auth route and default route.

```
http://example.com/auth/login
http://example.com/dashboard
```

First is handled by page auth.php and param page (EG: http://example.com/auth.php?page=login). The second is handled by index.php and param page (EG: http://example.com/index.php?page=dashboard).

I've made the .htaccess file using an online generator, It's something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^auth/([^/]*)$ /auth.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But this cause Error 500, commenting the second line I'm able to reach the auth page with the login param.

Apache2 error.log wrote only this, related to server start:

```
[Thu Jan 26 20:31:04.795013 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7163] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 26 20:31:04.795100 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7163] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2'
```

Comment: As always with an http status 500: that is an internal error, so take a look at your http servers error log file to get more specific information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, since I'm in c9 ide I can't access the apache log file, when I reach the /var/log/apache2 dir i got both the files (errors.log and access.log) blank, so I don't know how to find the logs

Comment: Then take a look into your http servers host configuration, that is where the location of the log files is configured. If they are _not_ configured, then enable them. You _cannot_ program php in a web environment without monitoring that log file. It is like flying blind inside a narrow cave.

Comment: It says ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log and LogLevel warn. but as I said this file is blank.

Comment: Maybe file system permissions? And what is `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` actually? Can't tell you, only you have access, but you definitely want to sort that out.

Comment: I can't understand, I've changed the ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} with full part of an error.log file created in my workspace dir, so I've tried to repeat the error, I will update the question with the only two lines that was stored in the file

Comment: Those are the startup entries, that is fine. You get no additional entry, even if you see the error 500 in your browser? Do a deep reload please.

Comment: I've tried to stop the server and reloading using service apache2 start but nothing changed, there is a parameter to start apache and force logging?

Comment: Depends on your distribution. Could be `service apache2 restart` or `rcapache2 restart` or some init script under `/etc/init.d/apache2`. There is no way to "force logging", the daemon will load what logging is configured.

Answer (score 1):

You have to exclude the destination you are rewriting to otherwise you will get a rewrite loop error since the pattern **([^/]+)** also matches **/index.php** . So change your first rule to this :

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index.php).+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It's working, but this broke my javascript assets, i got Unexpected token '<' in all my files including jquery